# unit testing for socket python

Tags: python, sockets

Can someone help on doing unit testing please? The aim for my program is to connect to the iKettle. This is my code:

```
ip_address = ""
port = 2000
def handShake(self, ip_address):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect((ip_address, self.port))
        s.send("HELLOKETTLE")
        self.kettleResponse(s)
        s.close()
    except:
        print("error connecting")
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: How would I implement unit testing on this?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you need one level of abstraction above that of working with sockets. Something like entity that handles sending and receiving response.

Then you go and make specialization of it, that creates socket, sends data, receives response, etc. That one you use in real scenarios.

However, to have something that is good for unit tests, you go and mock this entity to have dummy methods that do nothing and return what you want them to.

Now you apparently think, well this is not testing anything. And you are right. However, I don't think you should unit test socket communication, but methods and functions that process data that is sent/received.

Other approach is to create localhost server on desired port that will respond with data given in advance. But that is nothing more than above mentioned approach but with more overhead of creating server side, defining protocol  etc., and all of that just for unit test.

Comment: And how would I unit test the methods that send/receive data from the socket?

Comment: You can use Python's `unittest` and `mock` libraries. Pay attention to examples in quick guide. There you have `assert_called_with` etc. that you can use to make sure methods are called. Also, you can mock what those methods return.

Comment: Do you mind giving an example please? say for: result = s.recv(2048)
                print(result)